# sun.security.ssl.allowUnsafeRenegotiation

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jvm, ssl-certificate, websphere-7

Does the option "-Dsun.security.ssl.allowUnsafeRenegotiation=true" work in IBM's JVM that ships with WebSphere 7

Answer (score 1):

No. What would work is

> com.ibm.jsse2.renegotiate=none

But even this option works only after you install the actualy fixes for the [renegotiating vulnerabilities](http://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2009-3555). The level with the required fixes is SR6.